# TextField Redirects to main page after animation finishes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, textfield

I have been trying to use a sylized input field from `@material-ui` but when doing this:

```
<TextField
  id="outlined-basic"
  className={classes.inputField}
  color="primary"
  label="Message"
  variant="filled"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

After the animation occurs when the user clickes on it they are redirected from `localhost:3000/some-page` to `localhost:3000` in my tests. Here is the handleChange function as well:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({text: e.target.value})
}
```

I have the exact same code in another react project yet I am still getting this problem and cannot figure out why. All help on this would be appreciated! Thanks.

## Edit:

Here is the full code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ".././App.css";
import { Title } from "../Components/Title";

// MUI Stuff
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button/Button";

// Theme
import theme from "../Util/theme";

const styles = {
  ...theme.spreadIt,
};


class BugsMain extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.id = "0";
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Title title="Bugs | Root_Directory" />
          <p>
            <h1> Feedback </h1>
          </p>
          <a className="App-link" href="/">
            <Button className={classes.button} href="">Submit A Bug Report</Button> <br /> <br />
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              className={classes.inputField}
              color="primary"
              label="Message"
              variant="filled"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            /><br />
            <Button className={classes.button} href={"/bug-viewer?id=" + this.id}>Find A Bug Report</Button> <br /> <br />
            <Button className={classes.button} href="/">Return to home</Button>
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
};


export default withStyles(styles)(BugsMain);
```

Comment: what is the result if you remove onChange from the TextField temporarily?

Comment: The exact same thing happens.

Comment: can you attach the whole codebase?

Comment: Sure I'll add it in an edit

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to do any navigation in `handleChange`? Is this component being rendered in a form? Are you sure it isn't one of the buttons or anchor tag that triggers the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `TextField` is placed inside the `a` tag.
Please move `TextField` outside of the `a` tag.

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually didn't notice this!

Comment: or just try to remove `href="/"` from the `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

The `<className="App-link" href="/">` its the reason, you should have a Redirection or some logic if send with no error to redirect to certain page...